# Android: How to get id of ImageView without using onclick() event

Tags: android, android-imageview

Here's my XML :

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/IVtarih1"
               android:layout_height="125dp" 
               android:layout_width="125dp" />
```

And my Activity

```
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IV1);
    new DownloadImageTask(image1).execute(urlStr1);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IV2)

    iv.setImageResource(R.id.image1);//I can't find id of image1
```

I'm getting the background of image1 from an url. So i don't have any drawable. I want to set background of image1 to ImageView iv. How can I do this? I thought that if I find the id of image1 I can achive this. The id of image1 is changing every runtime.

Comment: Does "didn't work" mean you got an error?  If so, could you copy it here?  Or did it return the wrong ID?  Or something else?

Comment: Are you trying to get the ID of the ImageView or the ID of the drawable?  Also, why?

Comment: @Iztaka, The code above didn't changed value of id. Didn't give an error

Comment: @Simon, I am trying to get the ID of the ImageView. I'll use the id as parameter to the method of setImageResouce() .

Answer (score 1):

Set the id in the XML ahead of time like

```
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then in your Activity you can get it by

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused. You don't need the *ImageView's* id for that. You just need to do `imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable_name)`.